# Windows Sandbox PowerShell logon command window not visible

Tags: powershell, windows-sandbox

I'm trying to use Windows Sandbox with a PowerShell logon command. This is the `LogonCommand` section of my WSB file:

```xml
  <LogonCommand>
    <Command>C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -file "C:\\Users\\WDAGUtilityAccount\\Desktop\\boot.ps1" -noexit</Command>
  </LogonCommand>
```

The Windows Sandbox instance loads up okay suggesting no syntactic/validation issues with the WSB file content, but the PowerShell window is not shown. Adding `-windowstyle normal` has no effect.

I suspect the `LogonCommand` content is run in a command prompt which is not made visible so running the command to open PowerShell from it somehow "inherits" the terminal window not being visible.

Is it possible to force the PowerShell terminal window to reveal itself in such a case? I want to do this so that I can see the errors that I get because the PowerShell script is not executing as expected and I'm blind to any output/progress indication.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found *an* answer (doesn't look like the cleanest option, but works):

```xml
<Command>powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted -command "start powershell {-noexit -file C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Desktop\boot.ps1}"</Command>
```

- `powershell` switches from CMD to PowerShell

  - `-windowstyle normal` won't work to make this PowerShell window visible
  - `-executionpolicy unrestricted` allows the nested PowerShell to run from file
- `start powershell` runs another PowerShell with visible window

  - Running this directly for `LogonCommand` will not work
  - `-noexit` tells the nested PowerShell to remain visible

    - This is not necessary but it is useful for debugging the script errors
  - `-file C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Desktop\boot.ps1` runs the given script

    - Share it with the machine by using a `MappedFolder` in the WSB configuration

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I was struggling too.

Comment: You can simplify `C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe` to `powershell.exe` as the rest is in the environment variable `%path%`. Thanks though, this was a pain to get working.

Comment: @AlexKwitny surprised that it worked for you as it did not work for me - but it has been a while since I tried so I am glad to hear it works now.

Comment: It has probably since been fixed and I believe you that it didn't work previously. The moment sandbox came out I was playing with it and it had all sorts of `.net` errors. They've improved it I think a good amount since then.

Comment: @AlexKwitny can you confirm leaving out the `.exe` works? It should right?

Comment: Confirmed, dropping the `.exe` works as well as the double "\\" can be "\". This worked just fine `<Command>powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted -command "start powershell {-noexit -file C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Desktop\ReadOnly\StartupScripts\MainScript.ps1}"</Command>`

Comment: Can you explain the curly braces? While it looks like a syntax error, it actually works though. IMO they shouldn't be necessary so I suspect some strange command parsing things going on.