# Windows sandbox and Powershell : how to make script executable at startup

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-sandbox

I followed tutorial to do so :

in wsb:

```
<LogonCommand>
  <Command>powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted -command "start powershell {-noexit -file C:\scripts\start.ps1}"</Command>
</LogonCommand>
```

in start.ps1 :

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
Set-ExecutionPolicy -scope CurrentUser Unrestricted
```

but when I try to run a script in sandbox, it still complains script is not executable.

Comment: This command works for me. Can you show your whole .wsb file? Maybe you have incorrect `<MappedFolders>` entry. Linked: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64795150/7571258

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Unrestricted, but everything works fine with RemoteSigned. If your script is blocked because it was downloaded from the internet, you can use the cmdlet Unblock-File

Comment: Can you give more details on how to "*use the cmdlet Unblock-File*"?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to nest the commands that deep. And since it's a set and forget command, you don't need the console to stay open (except for debugging purposes).

I.e. this would start notepad twice from within PowerShell and the exit

```
powershell -command "notepad.exe; notepad.exe"
```

So setting the Executionpolicy for `CurrentUser` only would be

```
<LogonCommand>
  <Command />powershell -command "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned"
</LogonCommand>
```